# GnuPG --> How do I list only the keys that have my signature

Tags: gnupg, digital-signature, public-key

I use my signature to validate a public key.
If someone's public the key is signed by me, then it is considered secure to encrypt and send emails to that recipient.

Is there a command under gpg that allows me to ask if a particular public key is signed by me, or do I need to use --list-sigs keyID and then look for my signature in the output?